# ToString () in java Can't make a \t

Tags: java

So I have a to string method and I want to print an Arraylist with a tab after each one

```
public String toString() {
    return plate + "  " + year + "  " + mfg + " " + style + "  " + color + "\\t"; 
}
```

This is where I'm calling

```
System.out.println(resultList.toString());
```

And I get result  all in one line with `[ ]`.

Comment: Where is your toString() method defined? Calling toString() on an `ArrayList` object will print out `[]` for an empty list.

Comment: I dont get empty list I have values in the array

Comment: "*get result all in one line*" - a tab won't change anything there, it will always be in one line. Did you mean `\n`, for a new line?

Comment: my output is [plate + year + mfg + style + color and tab doesnt help]

Answer (score 5):

Use `"\t"` not `"\\t"`. The latter outputs a literal `\` followed by a `t`.

---

However, this is a little bit of a code smell. You generally shouldn't be doing output formatting like this in `toString()`, it may be OK for your simple use case but if you make a habit out of it it can cause issues and confusion in larger applications. At minimum, consider the tab to be part of your UI, and keep it at a slightly higher level, e.g.:

```
for (Result r : resultList) {
    System.out.println(r + "\t");
}
```

Even better, consider doing *all* formatting at a higher level rather than in `toString()`, e.g.:

```
for (Result r : resultList) {
    System.out.println(r.getPlate() + " " + r.getYear() + " " +
                       r.getMfg() + " " + r.getStyle() + " " +
                       r.getColor() + "\t");
}
```

Your usage of `toString()` is certainly convenient and may make sense for your application, and it isn't inherently *evil*, but just be aware of what you are doing. Generally (but certainly not always), `toString()` is used for debugging, not formatting of composite objects.

Comment: great it did work, is it posbile to use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog PLAIN_MESSAGE);  ??They pop up in differen Windows

Comment: @user3191018 If you wanted to display everything in a single message box, you would have to construct a single `String` that contains all of the data then display that string. It's about the same as above, but use e.g. `String s = resultList.toString()` or loop and do `s += singleResultString` or something first. Goal is to get everything in one `String`, *then* show message box.

Answer (score 3):

You need to unescape the Tab. Change `\\t` to `\t`

Your version has Java escaping the `\`, so `\\` produces the character literal `\` which goes adjacent to the following `t`. You want to escape the t, not the `\`, so write `\t` which produces a tab character.

If you're looking to write every result on a new line, then you need to replace `\t` with the newline character `\n`.

Comment: What reaction are you looking for exactly?

Comment: so array contains of 2 elements right now(but can be different each time) I'm looking for one vehicle per line...

Comment: @user3191018 Then you will want to use `"\n"` as Kon suggests; since a tab is not a newline.